# HIbernate 4: Mapping last audit row as association property

Tags: hibernate, subquery, join

I need to map two classes Person and PersonAudit:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private PersonAudit personAudit;

    public Person() {
    }

    //getters and setters omitted
}

public class PersonAudit implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private Person person;
    private String name;
    private String user;
    private Date date;

    public PersonAudit() {
    }

    //getters and setters omitted
}
```

The table PersonAudit stores the historical changes on Person table.

Is it possible to map the **Person.personAudit** property to get always the last audit register, considering that Person table doesn't actually have any column referencing PersonAudit table?

I'm following the Employee-Employment-Organization documentation's example (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#assoc-complex) but it seems to work only if Employee table includes an orgId column.

This is the mapping of Person class so far:

```
<class catalog="test" name="test.Person" table="Person">
    <id name="id" type="int">
      <column name="Id"/>
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
      <column length="30" name="Name" not-null="true"/>
    </property>

    <join table="PersonAudit"> 
        <subselect>
            select Id,IdPerson
            from PersonAudit
            group by IdPerson
            having Id = max(Id)
        </subselect>
        <key column="Id" />
        <many-to-one name="personAudit" class="test.PersonAudit" column="???"/>
    </join>
</class>
```

So, many-to-one isn't the way to go, how can I resolve this scenario?

Any help I'll appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a formula reference is good for this scenario. Off the top of my head it should look somehow like:

```
<many-to-one name="personAudit"
  formula="(SELECT Max(pa.Id) FROM PersonAudit pa WHERE pa.IdPerson = Id)" > 
</many-to-one>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who may need to map this kind of association as a component, this is another way to solve this scenario:

```
<join table="PersonAudit" optional="true"> 
        <subselect>
            select pa.Id,pa.IdPerson,pa.Name,pa.User,pa.Date
            from PersonAudit pa
            where pa.Id = 
                ( select max(Id)
                    from PersonAudit
                    where IdPerson = Id)
        </subselect>    
        <key column="IdPerson" />
        <component name="personAudit" class="test.PersonAudit">
            <property name="id" column="Id"/>
            <property name="name" column="Name"/>
            <property name="user" column="USer"/>
            <property name="date" column="Date"/>
        </component>
</join>
```